# Amchart X axis position and fill to axis

Tags: graph, charts, amcharts

I am using AmChartXY to draw graph areas, here is the fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ap60fhsu/1/

```
            var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
            "type": "xy",
            "autoMarginOffset": 20,
            "dataProvider": [{
                "ax": 0,
                "ay": 0,
                "bx": 0,
                "by": 0,
            }, {
                "ax": 8,
                "ay": 1,
                "bx": 12,
                "by": -2,
            },
            {
                "ax": 32,
                "ay": 9,
                "bx": 35,
                "by": -1,
            },
            {
                "ax": 45,
                "ay": 6,
                "bx": 45,
                "by": -2,
            },
            {
                "ax": 60,
                "ay": 2,
                "bx": 60,
                "by": -2,
            },
            {
                "ax": 70,
                "ay": 0,
                "bx": 70,
                "by": 0,
            },
            {
                "ax": 75,
                "ay": 0,
                "bx": 72,
                "by": 0,

            },
            {
                "ax": 85,
                "ay": 6,
                "bx": 80,
                "by": -1,
            },
            {
                "ax": 90,
                "ay": 0,
                "bx": 90,
                "by": 0,
            }],
            "valueAxes": [ {
                "position": "bottom",
                "axisAlpha": 0,
                "dashLength": 1,
                "id": "x",
                "title": "X Axis"
            }, {
                "axisAlpha": 0,
                "dashLength": 1,
                "position": "left",
                "id": "y",
                "title": "Y Axis"
            }],
            "plotAreaBorderAlpha": 1,
            "startDuration": 1,
            "graphs": [ {
                "balloonText": "x:[[x]] y:[[y]]",
                "fillAlphas": 0.3,
                "fillToAxis": "x",
                "lineAlpha": 1,
                "xField": "ax",
                "yField": "ay",
                "lineColor": "#FF6600"
            }, {
                "balloonText": "x:[[x]] y:[[y]]",
                "lineAlpha": 1,
                "fillToAxis": "x",
                "fillAlphas": 0.3,
                "xField": "bx",
                "yField": "by",
                "lineColor": "#FCD202"
            }],
            "marginLeft": 64,
            "marginBottom": 60,
            "chartScrollbar": {},
            "chartCursor": {},
            "export": {
                "enabled": true,
                "position": "bottom-right"
            }
        });
```

As you see I have negative values for Y axis, this makes the X axis fall down from Y=0 to Y=-4 and when I use fillToAxis: x, expecting that the graph fill areas will be areas bounded with graphs and X axis corresponding to the value Y=0, I get another result. How can I move the X axis to the Y=0, or at least get the fill area result as I expect?

Thanks in advance

Comment: just made an update to the fiddle: jsfiddle.net/ap60fhsu/2/, removing the x axis position works for the area to be filled correctly, in this case only the problem is left aligned and rotated x axis label

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible to either move the acual X axis to the middle of plot area, nor make the graph fill to negative value. To make the chart more comprehensible you can place a guide on 0 mark to make it look like an axis line: http://jsfiddle.net/ap60fhsu/5/